# Number of decompositions of 20 into four integer parts

Tags: combinatorics

How many solutions are there to the equation: $a + b + c + d = 20$, where $a, b, c,$ and $d$ are non-negative integers?

I was thinking the answer would be $\displaystyle{N+1-p \choose p}$ something along those lines. We really have $1$ free variable I assume.

This may be resemblant of the fact of derangements, combinations and/or factorials..

Comment: I think this is actually the [partition numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Partition.html) that you're interested in.

Comment: This is known as the stars and bars problem, see e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Comment: @RichardWang Which missing part in my answer prevented you to reach a full solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine 20 beads on a line,
$$\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ,$$
that you want to group into four groups (empty groups allowed).

The key question is: **In how many ways can you place three delimiters?**

For example, the partition $2+8+1+9=20$ is represented by
$$\circ\circ|\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ|\circ|\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ,$$
and the partition $3+0+16+1$ is represented by
$$\circ\circ\circ||\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ\circ|\circ.$$

Comment: what is the final format, i.e. answer it takes? was my predicition correct?

Comment: @RichardWang: I think you were not entirely right. I think you can place the 20 beads and the three delimiters in $\frac{(20+3)!}{20!3!}$ unique ways. This is the same answer as Did got.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $u(x)=\frac1{(1-x)^4}$, then
$$
u(x)=\sum_ax^a\sum_bx^b\sum_cx^c\sum_dx^d=\sum_{a,b,c,d}x^{a+b+c+d},
$$
and
$$
u(x)=\frac16\frac{\mathrm d^3}{\mathrm dx^3}\frac1{1-x}=\frac16\frac{\mathrm d^3}{\mathrm dx^3}\sum_ix^i=\frac16\sum_i(i+3)(i+2)(i+1)x^i,
$$
hence
$$
u(x)=\sum_i{i+3\choose3}x^i,
$$
and the answer is the coefficient of $x^{20}$ in $u(x)$, that is, ${20+3\choose3}$.