# Random variables and permutations

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I'm trying find the number of ordered triples of non-negative integers $a, b, c$ whose sum $a + b + c$ is a given positive integer $n$. I've related it to the concept of distinguishable balls in distinguishable boxes, but can't seem to see what's missing.

Comment: Which part of this question is not a duplicate of [this previous one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/372331/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can reframe the problem to see that this is precisely the problem of distributing $n$ apples to 3 people (apples indistinguishable, people distinguishable), ensuring that each person gets at least one apple. We can then reframe THIS problem by distributing one apple to each person, and then considering the number of distributions of $n-3$ apples to 3 people.

If this is sufficient, great! If not, keep reading.

To solve the problem of distributing $n-3$ apples to 3 people, note this is the same as the problem of placing 2 dividers between $n-3$ apples, where two adjacent dividers means that no apples were distributed to that person. This is the same as taking $n-3 + 2$ objects and choosing 2 to be dividers (The remaining $n-3$ will be apples). Hence, our answer is ${n-3 + 2 \choose 2}$.